# Conveying the idea of "the biggest travesty"

Tags: expressions, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, argot, cinéma

L'autre jour, parlant des réalisateurs Sergio Leone et Stanley Kubrick, j'ai voulu dire en français :

> Stanley Kubrick and Sergio Leonne didn't win an Oscar in Best Film/Best Director categories. This is the biggest travesty.

or in a similar manner

> The Good, the Bad and the Ugly is among the best films ever made. It didn't win a Oscar even for Best Editing/Best Music. That's a travesty.

Je savais que les mots travesti(r) et travestissement existent en français.
Donc j'ai dit

> Vous le croyez ? Le film Le Bon la Brute et le Truand n'a pas gagné un seul Oscar. Quelle travesti.

> Le plus grand travestissement ? Sergio Leone et Stanley Kubrick n'ont pas gagné même un seul Oscar du Meilleur Film/ Meilleur Réalisateur.

Je n'ai été pas compris par mes interlocuteurs, locuteurs natifs du français. J'ai dû donc rendre le sens de l'expression anglaise métaphoriquement.

Questions :

1. Les expressions

> C'est une travesti/ C'est un travestissement

sont-elles utilisées en français avec le sens de "this is a travesty"?

2. Linguee donne https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=this+is+a+travesty

> C'est absurde/insensé/mascarade/simulacre

entre autres, pour *This is a travesty*. Pourrait-on utiliser ces expressions dans ce contexte ?

3. Quelles autres expressions rendent une idée similaire ?

Nota bene

https://www.grammar.com/travesty-vocabulary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In judicial matters "travesty" is rendered in French by *parodie*:

- [A travesty of justice](https://www.amnesty.org/en/latest/news/2018/02/turkey-rearrest-of-amnesty-chair-devastates-family-disgraces-justice/),  *[une parodie de justice](https://www.amnesty.fr/liberte-d-expression/actualites/une-parodie-de-justice-pour-taner-kilic)*.

*simulacre de justice* can also be used but it is less frequent in the press and among organisations.

None of the expressions around *travesti* you propose would work in French.

*[Un travesti](http://travesti)* is an actor or someone who dresses as someone of the opposite sex (a tranvestite).
*[Un travestissement](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/travestissement)* is a disguise.

*Mascarade* could work perfectly fine.

- Ils n'ont jamais reçu d'Oscar, c'est une vraie mascarade.

But not [simulacre](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/simulacre) or *[parodie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parodie)* because we would not use them on their own in this sense, or we'd have to say something like:

- *C'est un simulacre/une parodie de remise de prix/de récompenses*.

If we want to stay in keeping with the judicial aspect carried by "travesty"  then the best would be to to say *injustice*.

- *C'est une injustice*.

Answer (score 5):

[Travesti](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/travesti/) en français, veut dire déguisé, dissimulé ou masqué. Mais souvent, ce mot est employé pour définir un homme qui s'habille comme les femmes (*ou l'inverse*).

Pour répondre à ta question, **«Quelle travestie»** n'est absolument pas l'expression que tu cherches mais plutôt «**C'est ridicule**» ou bien **«C'est absurde»**, ainsi que les autres expressions que tu as mentionné.

Je voudrais préciser que je ne suis pas natif et qu'il est très plausible que je me sois gouré, en espérant que quelqu'un de plus capable passe par là et me corrige si j'ai écrit une connerie.

Comment: Bienvenu à FSE. Merci pour la réponse.

Answer (score 2):

L'idée de travestissement exprime essentiellement *changer une chose en quelque chose d'autre* (de façon péjorative).

> Stanley Kubrick et Sergio Leonne n'ont pas gagné d'Oscars [...]. C'est une vaste fumisterie.

- Fumisterie : Action, chose entièrement dépourvu de sérieux (Le Petit Robert).

Answer (score -1):

Bien que d'autres réponses aient proposé des traductions irréprochables, je n'en partage pas les arguments, d'ailleurs sans référence, que le mot utilisé, « travestissement », ne convenait pas. Deux sources linguistiques prouvent cela, de plus que d'assez nombreux exemples dans des parutions récentes.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/travestissement)) B. − Au fig. Action d'altérer le caractère ou la nature de quelque chose. Synon. déformation, parodie

« Travestissement » sgnifie donc bien « parodie ».

> (Harrap's Dictionary) **travesty** travestissement *m* (d'une pièce de théâtre, etc.); parodie *f*; **a travesty of the truth** un travestissement de la vérité.

Il aurait peut-être été préférable de dire «  travestissement de vote », mais en l'absence du mot « vote » ou d'un autre mot à même de mentionner ce processus explicitement l'idée du processus de décision impliqué n'est pas si lointaine.

Il se trouve que depuis 1970 le mot  « travestissement » est de plus en plus utilisé ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=19&smoothing=3&content=travestissement&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctravestissement%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctravestissement%3B%2Cc0)) mais c'est très probablement dû à un emploi accru du mot dans son sens propre.
Néanmoins des emplois récents comme ceux ci-dessous montrent que ce terme est encore de notre temps.

([réf. 1, 2011](https://books.google.fr/books?id=skPxRgUPGZ4C&pg=PA35&dq=%22travestissement%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAlZ3_g4fsAhVjx4UKHSSCDqU4ZBDoATBFegQIHhAC#v=onepage&q=%22travestissement%22&f=false)) Envisager la mondialisation au Moyen Âge peut être, aux yeux de qui considère cette période comme un âge moyen, un contresens, voire un travestissement de l'histoire.

([réf. 2, 2004](https://books.google.fr/books?id=6ZhwAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT133&dq=%22travestissement%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAlZ3_g4fsAhVjx4UKHSSCDqU4ZBDoATBIegQIJRAC#v=onepage&q=%22travestissement%22&f=false))  Par un habile et homogène travestissement, le consommateur et le citoyen se fondent de plus en plus dans une seule et même personne.

([réf. 3, 2015](https://books.google.fr/books?id=qxSiBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT4&dq=%22travestissement%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAlZ3_g4fsAhVjx4UKHSSCDqU4ZBDoATBSegQIHxAC#v=onepage&q=%22travestissement%22&f=false)) Quels résultats espère-t-on de ce travestissement de la vérité ? Il est malaisé de le discerner.

([réf. 4, 2005](https://books.google.fr/books?id=qsWbjKj5g44C&pg=RA15-PA77&dq=%22travestissement%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAlZ3_g4fsAhVjx4UKHSSCDqU4ZBDoATBUegQIFhAC#v=onepage&q=%22travestissement%22&f=false)) Le déguisement du personnage accompagne le travestissement de la réalité féodale .

([réf. 5, 2014](https://books.google.fr/books?id=EvtmBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT7&dq=%22travestissement%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAlZ3_g4fsAhVjx4UKHSSCDqU4ZBDoATBhegQIABAC#v=onepage&q=%22travestissement%22&f=false)) Travestissement, escamotage du réel.

([réf. 6](https://books.google.fr/books?id=wsdgAIBbLfYC&pg=PA91&dq=%22travestissement%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT4Jm1iofsAhWIx4UKHSLFDsU4yAEQ6AEwB3oECCkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22travestissement%22&f=false)) à. la. ,. métaphysique .. d'un. double enlisement beckettien, voire au travestissement, à la manière pompidolienne, d'une injustice de classe en simple cas social.

([réf. 7, 2005](https://books.google.fr/books?id=99xr6YHYMIoC&pg=PT67&dq=%22travestissement%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT4Jm1iofsAhWIx4UKHSLFDsU4yAEQ6AEwVHoECBMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22travestissement%22&f=false)) un article posthume, réaffirme son opinion favorable au vote familial avec répartition équitable des voix362,natalistes et familialistes sont pour une fois entièrement d'accord pour refuser le dangereux travestissement du suffrage familial.

([réf. 8, 2013](https://books.google.fr/books?id=IQRWAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT32&dq=%22travestissement%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT4Jm1iofsAhWIx4UKHSLFDsU4yAEQ6AEwVXoECDEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22travestissement%22&f=false)) lui même, la simulation, la tromperie et le jeu lui semblent non seulement loisibles mais nécessaires. Vu ce qu'il croit du monde et de lui même, il a tout intérêt à mentir. Dans sa quête de la sincérité originelle, le travestissement de soi et la manipulation des autres sont donc son avenir et son meilleur atout.

Comment: Vu qu'il semble impossible de ne pas s'étendre dans une longue discussion, tous les commentaires ont été [transférés vers un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113480/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-conveying-the-idea-of-the-biggest-travesty).